# HostnameVerifier correct implementation

Tags: android, google-play, android-security

I am trying to publish my app in google play and getting this message from Google Play.

We rejected your App, with package name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the issue

HostnameVerifier 
Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

Here's how i am using it:

```
static HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        if(hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("staging.hostname") || hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("production.sostname")){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

};
```

And calling it like this:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) requestURL
            .openConnection();

    conn.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: here which value is hostname? @Ishan Khanduja

Comment: your package name ?

Answer (score 0):

Your verifier is really not safe. See the range of checks that the default verifier performs: [OkHostnameVerifier](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/refs/heads/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/tls/OkHostnameVerifier.java). This is actually the best practice – to leave this verification to the platform.

You may add your extra checks on top of it, e.g. restrict the hostnames. If your servers lack Server Name Indication, you may look how Google were working around this until 2014: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/cc0952ec282184914a6153e9deff458c94785fd1%5E%21.